# send push notification using php code but does not send notification in ios

Tags: php, ios

I have below my php code to send a push notification on an ios mobile device but the notification is not being sent. I have a device token working.

When I connect the iPhone to a mac and run the app it installs then sends a push notification successfully but when I download the app from the app store it is not working.

```
//send notification code
function send_apns($deviceToken,$body){

$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'vision');
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', VIS_PATH_PLUGINS.'iphone/ckProd.pem');
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $ctx);
stream_set_blocking ($fp, 0);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "Failed to connect (stream_socket_client): $err $errstrn";
} else {

    $apple_expiry = time() + (90 * 24 * 60 * 60);
    $apple_identifier = 1;
    $payload = json_encode($body);
    $msg = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $deviceToken)) . chr(0) . chr(strlen($payload)) . $payload;
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));
    print_r($body);  
    fclose($fp);
    if (!$result)
        echo 'Message not delivered' . PHP_EOL;
    else
        echo 'Message successfully delivered' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

}

Comment: Attempting to clarify question which was badly formatted and had poor English.

Answer (score 0):

It is known that you have to use **different** `Pem Certificate and APNS Gateway` for development and production builds.

Since build from App Store is a production one, you should change **SSL address**

```
gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
```

to

`gateway.push.apple.com:2195`

and `VIS_PATH_PLUGINS.'iphone/ckProd.pem` to adress to your production pem certificate if you haven't changed it yet.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Your destination `'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195'` should not contains `sandbox` if you are sending push notification to live app so, remove `sandbox` from your destination, because `sandbox` is used if application is in development mode. Also you need to use `Pem Certificate and APNS Gateway` of production environment.